# Publish ivy artifacts to multiple resolvers at once

Tags: ant, ivy

Our main problem is this:
We have two ivy repositories and we want them to be mirrors of each other.  So anytime we publish an artifact, we want the artifacts to go to both repositories.  We previously only had one repository, so we have many existing projects that already publish to that one repository.  We don't want to have to go into those many projects and add a second publish target, so we are trying to see if we can accomplish this though the ivy settings.

So I'm trying to find out if it is possible to make Ivy publish artifacts to multiple repositories at the same time.  My best guess was to use a chain resolver to publish to, but ivy seems to only choose the first resolver in the chain and then stops.  So does anyone know how we can accomplish this without calling publish twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/chain.html) says following about chain-resolvers:

```
Handle publish  delegates to first sub resolver in chain
```

The dual-resolver is not up to the task, too.

So it won't be possible to use a chain for multiple publishing. Which I expected to work, too.

Therefore you have to call the `<publish />` task twice. Once for each destination.

Or maybe you need a different mirroring approach, that does not involve ivy .